# Presentation created in C# with the Open XML SDK is corrupted and blank when opened

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, presentationml

## Problem

I am trying to create a PowerPoint presentation in `C#` with Visual Studio using the `Open XML SDK`.

The presentation I create contains one slide with one table with 3 rows and 2 columns.

When I try to open the PowerPoint presentation created by the program, I am presented with the following error message:

```
PowerPoint found a problem with content in test3.pptx.
PowerPoint can attempt to repair the presentation.

If you trust the source of this presentation, click Repair.
```

When I click Repair, I am presented with another error message:

```
PowerPoint couldn't read some content in test3.pptx - Repaired and removed it.

Please check your presentation to see if the rest looks ok.
```

When I click Ok and check the contents of the presentation, it is empty.

## QUESTION

How should I modify the program, so users can open the presentations without problems?

- Am I using the wrong version of the `Open XML SDK`?
- Is there something wrong with the code I've written?
- Are there tools I can use to assist me in tracking down the error?
- Other?

## The version of PowerPoint I use to open the .pptx file

`Microsoft® PowerPoint® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2310 Build 16.0.16924.20054) 64-bit`

## My console project looks like this

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.20.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

## My main program looks like this

```cs
var builder = new OpenXMLBuilder.Test3();
builder.Doit(args);
```

## My source code looks like this

```cs
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using D = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;

#region disable_warnings
// Remove unnecessary suppression
#pragma warning disable IDE0079
// Member 'x' does not access instance data and can be marked as static
#pragma warning disable CA1822
// Remove unused parameter 'x'
#pragma warning disable IDE0060
// 'using' statement can be simplified
#pragma warning disable IDE0063
// 'new' expression can be simplified
#pragma warning disable IDE0090
// Object initialization can be simplified
#pragma warning disable IDE0017
#endregion

namespace OpenXMLBuilder
{
    class Test3
    {
        public void Doit(string[] args)
        {
            string filepath = "test3.pptx";
            CreatePresentation(filepath);
        }

        public static void CreatePresentation(string filepath)
        {
            // Create a presentation at a specified file path.
            using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Create(filepath, PresentationDocumentType.Presentation))
            {
                PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.AddPresentationPart();
                presentationPart.Presentation = new Presentation();
                CreateSlide(presentationPart);
            }
        }

        private static void CreateSlide(PresentationPart presentationPart)
        {
            // Create the SlidePart.
            SlidePart slidePart = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlidePart>();
            slidePart.Slide = new Slide(new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree()));

            // Declare and instantiate the table
            D.Table table = new D.Table();

            // Define the columns
            D.TableGrid tableGrid = new D.TableGrid();
            tableGrid.Append(new D.GridColumn() { Width = 3124200 });
            tableGrid.Append(new D.GridColumn() { Width = 3124200 });

            // Append the TableGrid to the table
            table.Append(tableGrid);

            // Create the rows and cells
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // 3 rows
            {
                D.TableRow row = new D.TableRow() { Height = 370840 };
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) // 2 columns
                {
                    D.TableCell cell = new D.TableCell();
                    D.TextBody body = new D.TextBody(new D.BodyProperties(),
                                                         new D.ListStyle(),
                                                         new D.Paragraph(new D.Run(new D.Text($"Cell {i + 1},{j + 1}"))));
                    cell.Append(body);
                    cell.Append(new D.TableCellProperties());
                    row.Append(cell);
                }
                table.Append(row);
            }

            // Create a GraphicFrame to hold the table
            GraphicFrame graphicFrame = new GraphicFrame();
            graphicFrame.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties = new NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties(
                new NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = 1026, Name = "Table" },
                new NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(),
                new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties());
            graphicFrame.Transform = new Transform(new D.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L }, new D.Extents() { Cx = 0L, Cy = 0L });
            graphicFrame.Graphic = new D.Graphic(new D.GraphicData(table)
            {
                Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table"
            });
            // Sanity check
            if (slidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("CreateSlide: CommonSlideData is null");
            if (slidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("CreateSlide: ShapeTree is null");
            // Append the GraphicFrame to the SlidePart
            slidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.AppendChild(graphicFrame);
            // Save the slide part
            slidePart.Slide.Save();

            // Create slide master
            SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlideMasterPart>();
            slideMasterPart.SlideMaster = new SlideMaster(new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree()));
            slideMasterPart.SlideMaster.Save();

            // Create slide layout
            SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart = slideMasterPart.AddNewPart<SlideLayoutPart>();
            slideLayoutPart.SlideLayout = new SlideLayout(new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree()));
            slideLayoutPart.SlideLayout.Save();
            // Create unique id for the slide
            presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList = new SlideIdList(new SlideId()
            {
                Id = 256U,
                RelationshipId = presentationPart.GetIdOfPart(slidePart)
            });
            // Set the size
            presentationPart.Presentation.SlideSize = new SlideSize() { Cx = 9144000, Cy = 6858000 };

            // Save the presentation
            presentationPart.Presentation.Save();
        }
    } // class
} // namespace
```

Comment: PowerPoint packages have more requirements to build a starting deck than Word or Excel packages.  One thing you might do is install the [Open XML SDK Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikeebowen.OOXMLSnippets) extension in Visual Studio and use it's CreatePresentation snippet  along with the Open XML SDK PowerPoint Utils item (a .cs file that has helper utility functions to build a package). Even if you don't use this directly in your final code, you will see what's needed to build a PowerPoint package from scratch.

Comment: Manually create the same PowerPoint, run your code to create a PowerPoint, rename both pptx files as .zip files, and then compare the two. That will give some hints as to what is missing.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that you are missing some hierarchy.
This Microsoft code is working, to take it by reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-presentation-document-by-providing-a-file-name

Comment: @tomjebo I used the snippets and the presentation turns out blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create a starting point similar to your (create a presentation and add a table to it).
The code is not super easy nor short, but I wasn't able to reduce it.
Still, it produces a new powerpoint with a table in the first page!

Code took by [Microsoft DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-presentation-document-by-providing-a-file-name) and [Microsoft sample](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/blob/master/OneCodeTeam/How%20to%20add%20a%20table%20with%20rows%20to%20PowerPoint%20using%20open%20xml/%5BC%23%5D-How%20to%20add%20a%20table%20with%20rows%20to%20PowerPoint%20using%20open%20xml/C%23/CSOpenXmlCreateTable/InsertTableToPowerPoint.cs)

```html
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using D = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using P = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using P14 = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.PowerPoint;

#region disable_warnings
// Remove unnecessary suppression
#pragma warning disable IDE0079
// Member 'x' does not access instance data and can be marked as static
#pragma warning disable CA1822
// Remove unused parameter 'x'
#pragma warning disable IDE0060
// 'using' statement can be simplified
#pragma warning disable IDE0063
// 'new' expression can be simplified
#pragma warning disable IDE0090
// Object initialization can be simplified
#pragma warning disable IDE0017
#endregion

namespace OpenXMLBuilder
{
    class Test2
    {
        public void Doit(string[] args)
        {
            string filepath = "test3.pptx";
            CreatePresentation(filepath);
        }

        public static void CreatePresentation(string filepath)
        {
            // Create a presentation at a specified file path. The presentation document type is pptx, by default.
            PresentationDocument presentationDoc = PresentationDocument.Create(filepath, PresentationDocumentType.Presentation);
            PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDoc.AddPresentationPart();
            presentationPart.Presentation = new Presentation();

            CreatePresentationParts(presentationPart);

            CreateTableInLastSlide(presentationDoc);
            //Close the presentation handle
            presentationPart.Presentation.Save();
            presentationDoc.Close();
        }

        private static void CreatePresentationParts(PresentationPart presentationPart)
        {
            SlideMasterIdList slideMasterIdList1 = new SlideMasterIdList(new SlideMasterId() { Id = (UInt32Value)2147483648U, RelationshipId = "rId1" });
            SlideIdList slideIdList1 = new SlideIdList(new SlideId() { Id = (UInt32Value)256U, RelationshipId = "rId2" });
            SlideSize slideSize1 = new SlideSize() { Cx = 9144000, Cy = 6858000, Type = SlideSizeValues.Screen4x3 };
            NotesSize notesSize1 = new NotesSize() { Cx = 6858000, Cy = 9144000 };
            DefaultTextStyle defaultTextStyle1 = new DefaultTextStyle();

            presentationPart.Presentation.Append(slideMasterIdList1, slideIdList1, slideSize1, notesSize1, defaultTextStyle1);

            SlidePart slidePart1;
            SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart1;
            SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart1;
            ThemePart themePart1;


            slidePart1 = CreateSlidePart(presentationPart);
            slideLayoutPart1 = CreateSlideLayoutPart(slidePart1);
            slideMasterPart1 = CreateSlideMasterPart(slideLayoutPart1);
            themePart1 = CreateTheme(slideMasterPart1);

            slideMasterPart1.AddPart(slideLayoutPart1, "rId1");
            presentationPart.AddPart(slideMasterPart1, "rId1");
            presentationPart.AddPart(themePart1, "rId5");
        }

        private static SlidePart CreateSlidePart(PresentationPart presentationPart)
        {
            // Create a GraphicFrame to hold the table
            SlidePart slidePart1 = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlidePart>("rId2");

            slidePart1.Slide = new Slide(
                    new CommonSlideData(
                        new ShapeTree(
                            new P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties(
                                new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "" },
                                new P.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties(),
                                new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties()),
                            new GroupShapeProperties(new D.TransformGroup()),
                            new P.Shape(
                                new P.NonVisualShapeProperties(
                                    new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)2U, Name = "Title 1" },
                                    new P.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new D.ShapeLocks() { NoGrouping = true }),
                                    new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new PlaceholderShape())),
                                new P.ShapeProperties(),
                                new P.TextBody(
                                    new D.BodyProperties(),
                                    new D.ListStyle(),
                                    new D.Paragraph(new D.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US" }))))),
                    new ColorMapOverride(new D.MasterColorMapping()));

            return slidePart1;
        }

        private static SlideLayoutPart CreateSlideLayoutPart(SlidePart slidePart1)
        {
            SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart1 = slidePart1.AddNewPart<SlideLayoutPart>("rId1");
            SlideLayout slideLayout = new SlideLayout(
            new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree(
              new P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties(
              new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "" },
              new P.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties(),
              new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties()),
              new GroupShapeProperties(new D.TransformGroup()),
              new P.Shape(
              new P.NonVisualShapeProperties(
                new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)2U, Name = "" },
                new P.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new D.ShapeLocks() { NoGrouping = true }),
                new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new PlaceholderShape())),
              new P.ShapeProperties(),
              new P.TextBody(
                new D.BodyProperties(),
                new D.ListStyle(),
                new D.Paragraph(new D.EndParagraphRunProperties()))))),
            new ColorMapOverride(new D.MasterColorMapping()));
            slideLayoutPart1.SlideLayout = slideLayout;
            return slideLayoutPart1;
        }

        private static SlideMasterPart CreateSlideMasterPart(SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart1)
        {
            SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart1 = slideLayoutPart1.AddNewPart<SlideMasterPart>("rId1");
            SlideMaster slideMaster = new SlideMaster(
            new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree(
              new P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties(
              new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "" },
              new P.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties(),
              new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties()),
              new GroupShapeProperties(new D.TransformGroup()),
              new P.Shape(
              new P.NonVisualShapeProperties(
                new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)2U, Name = "Title Placeholder 1" },
                new P.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new D.ShapeLocks() { NoGrouping = true }),
                new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new PlaceholderShape() { Type = PlaceholderValues.Title })),
              new P.ShapeProperties(),
              new P.TextBody(
                new D.BodyProperties(),
                new D.ListStyle(),
                new D.Paragraph())))),
            new P.ColorMap() { Background1 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Light1, Text1 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Dark1, Background2 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Light2, Text2 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Dark2, Accent1 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent1, Accent2 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent2, Accent3 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent3, Accent4 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent4, Accent5 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent5, Accent6 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent6, Hyperlink = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Hyperlink, FollowedHyperlink = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.FollowedHyperlink },
            new SlideLayoutIdList(new SlideLayoutId() { Id = (UInt32Value)2147483649U, RelationshipId = "rId1" }),
            new TextStyles(new TitleStyle(), new BodyStyle(), new OtherStyle()));
            slideMasterPart1.SlideMaster = slideMaster;

            return slideMasterPart1;
        }

        private static ThemePart CreateTheme(SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart1)
        {
            ThemePart themePart1 = slideMasterPart1.AddNewPart<ThemePart>("rId5");
            D.Theme theme1 = new D.Theme() { Name = "Office Theme" };

            D.ThemeElements themeElements1 = new D.ThemeElements(
            new D.ColorScheme(
              new D.Dark1Color(new D.SystemColor() { Val = D.SystemColorValues.WindowText, LastColor = "000000" }),
              new D.Light1Color(new D.SystemColor() { Val = D.SystemColorValues.Window, LastColor = "FFFFFF" }),
              new D.Dark2Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "1F497D" }),
              new D.Light2Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "EEECE1" }),
              new D.Accent1Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "4F81BD" }),
              new D.Accent2Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "C0504D" }),
              new D.Accent3Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "9BBB59" }),
              new D.Accent4Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "8064A2" }),
              new D.Accent5Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "4BACC6" }),
              new D.Accent6Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "F79646" }),
              new D.Hyperlink(new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "0000FF" }),
              new D.FollowedHyperlinkColor(new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "800080" }))
            { Name = "Office" },
              new D.FontScheme(
              new D.MajorFont(
              new D.LatinFont() { Typeface = "Calibri" },
              new D.EastAsianFont() { Typeface = "" },
              new D.ComplexScriptFont() { Typeface = "" }),
              new D.MinorFont(
              new D.LatinFont() { Typeface = "Calibri" },
              new D.EastAsianFont() { Typeface = "" },
              new D.ComplexScriptFont() { Typeface = "" }))
              { Name = "Office" },
              new D.FormatScheme(
              new D.FillStyleList(
              new D.SolidFill(new D.SchemeColor() { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor }),
              new D.GradientFill(
                new D.GradientStopList(
                new D.GradientStop(new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint() { Val = 50000 },
                  new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 300000 })
                { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                { Position = 0 },
                new D.GradientStop(new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint() { Val = 37000 },
                 new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 300000 })
                { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                { Position = 35000 },
                new D.GradientStop(new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint() { Val = 15000 },
                 new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 350000 })
                { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                { Position = 100000 }
                ),
                new D.LinearGradientFill() { Angle = 16200000, Scaled = true }),
              new D.NoFill(),
              new D.PatternFill(),
              new D.GroupFill()),
              new D.LineStyleList(
              new D.Outline(
                new D.SolidFill(
                new D.SchemeColor(
                  new D.Shade() { Val = 95000 },
                  new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 105000 })
                { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor }),
                new D.PresetDash() { Val = D.PresetLineDashValues.Solid })
              {
                  Width = 9525,
                  CapType = D.LineCapValues.Flat,
                  CompoundLineType = D.CompoundLineValues.Single,
                  Alignment = D.PenAlignmentValues.Center
              },
              new D.Outline(
                new D.SolidFill(
                new D.SchemeColor(
                  new D.Shade() { Val = 95000 },
                  new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 105000 })
                { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor }),
                new D.PresetDash() { Val = D.PresetLineDashValues.Solid })
              {
                  Width = 9525,
                  CapType = D.LineCapValues.Flat,
                  CompoundLineType = D.CompoundLineValues.Single,
                  Alignment = D.PenAlignmentValues.Center
              },
              new D.Outline(
                new D.SolidFill(
                new D.SchemeColor(
                  new D.Shade() { Val = 95000 },
                  new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 105000 })
                { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor }),
                new D.PresetDash() { Val = D.PresetLineDashValues.Solid })
              {
                  Width = 9525,
                  CapType = D.LineCapValues.Flat,
                  CompoundLineType = D.CompoundLineValues.Single,
                  Alignment = D.PenAlignmentValues.Center
              }),
              new D.EffectStyleList(
              new D.EffectStyle(
                new D.EffectList(
                new D.OuterShadow(
                  new D.RgbColorModelHex(
                  new D.Alpha() { Val = 38000 })
                  { Val = "000000" })
                { BlurRadius = 40000L, Distance = 20000L, Direction = 5400000, RotateWithShape = false })),
              new D.EffectStyle(
                new D.EffectList(
                new D.OuterShadow(
                  new D.RgbColorModelHex(
                  new D.Alpha() { Val = 38000 })
                  { Val = "000000" })
                { BlurRadius = 40000L, Distance = 20000L, Direction = 5400000, RotateWithShape = false })),
              new D.EffectStyle(
                new D.EffectList(
                new D.OuterShadow(
                  new D.RgbColorModelHex(
                  new D.Alpha() { Val = 38000 })
                  { Val = "000000" })
                { BlurRadius = 40000L, Distance = 20000L, Direction = 5400000, RotateWithShape = false }))),
              new D.BackgroundFillStyleList(
              new D.SolidFill(new D.SchemeColor() { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor }),
              new D.GradientFill(
                new D.GradientStopList(
                new D.GradientStop(
                  new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint() { Val = 50000 },
                    new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 300000 })
                  { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                { Position = 0 },
                new D.GradientStop(
                  new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint() { Val = 50000 },
                    new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 300000 })
                  { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                { Position = 0 },
                new D.GradientStop(
                  new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint() { Val = 50000 },
                    new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 300000 })
                  { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                { Position = 0 }),
                new D.LinearGradientFill() { Angle = 16200000, Scaled = true }),
              new D.GradientFill(
                new D.GradientStopList(
                new D.GradientStop(
                  new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint() { Val = 50000 },
                    new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 300000 })
                  { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                { Position = 0 },
                new D.GradientStop(
                  new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint() { Val = 50000 },
                    new D.SaturationModulation() { Val = 300000 })
                  { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                { Position = 0 }),
                new D.LinearGradientFill() { Angle = 16200000, Scaled = true })))
              { Name = "Office" });

            theme1.Append(themeElements1);
            theme1.Append(new D.ObjectDefaults());
            theme1.Append(new D.ExtraColorSchemeList());

            themePart1.Theme = theme1;
            return themePart1;

        }

        public static void CreateTableInLastSlide(PresentationDocument presentationDocument)
        {
            // Get the presentation Part of the presentation document
            PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;

            // Get the Slide Id collection of the presentation document
            var slideIdList = presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;

            if (slideIdList == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("The number of slide is empty, please select a ppt with a slide at least again");
            }

            // Get all Slide Part of the presentation document
            var list = slideIdList.ChildElements
                        .Cast<SlideId>()
                        .Select(x => presentationPart.GetPartById(x.RelationshipId))
                        .Cast<SlidePart>();

            // Get the last Slide Part of the presentation document
            var tableSlidePart = (SlidePart)list.Last();

            // Declare and instantiate the graphic Frame of the new slide
            GraphicFrame graphicFrame = tableSlidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.AppendChild(new GraphicFrame());

            // Specify the required Frame properties of the graphicFrame
            ApplicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension applicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension = new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension() { Uri = "{D42A27DB-BD31-4B8C-83A1-F6EECF244321}" };
            P14.ModificationId modificationId1 = new P14.ModificationId() { Val = 3229994563U };
            modificationId1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("p14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main");
            applicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension.Append(modificationId1);
            graphicFrame.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties = new NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties
            (new NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = 5, Name = "table 1" },
            new NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoGrouping = true }),
            new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtensionList(applicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension)));

            graphicFrame.Transform = new Transform(new A.Offset() { X = 1650609L, Y = 4343400L }, new A.Extents() { Cx = 6096000L, Cy = 741680L });

            // Specify the Griaphic of the graphic Frame
            graphicFrame.Graphic = new A.Graphic(new A.GraphicData(GenerateTable()) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table" });
            presentationPart.Presentation.Save();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate Table as below order:
        /// a:tbl(Table) ->a:tr(TableRow)->a:tc(TableCell)
        /// We can return TableCell object with CreateTextCell method
        /// and Append the TableCell object to TableRow 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Table Object</returns>
        private static A.Table GenerateTable()
        {
            string[,] tableSources = new string[,] { { "name", "age" }, { "Tom", "25" } };

            // Declare and instantiate table 
            A.Table table = new A.Table();

            // Specify the required table properties for the table
            A.TableProperties tableProperties = new A.TableProperties() { FirstRow = true, BandRow = true };
            A.TableStyleId tableStyleId = new A.TableStyleId();
            tableStyleId.Text = "{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}";

            tableProperties.Append(tableStyleId);

            // Declare and instantiate tablegrid and colums
            A.TableGrid tableGrid1 = new A.TableGrid();
            A.GridColumn gridColumn1 = new A.GridColumn() { Width = 3048000L };
            A.GridColumn gridColumn2 = new A.GridColumn() { Width = 3048000L };

            tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn1);
            tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn2);
            table.Append(tableProperties);
            table.Append(tableGrid1);
            for (int row = 0; row < tableSources.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                // Instantiate the table row
                A.TableRow tableRow = new A.TableRow() { Height = 370840L };
                for (int column = 0; column < tableSources.GetLength(1); column++)
                {
                    tableRow.Append(CreateTextCell(tableSources.GetValue(row, column).ToString()));
                }

                table.Append(tableRow);
            }

            return table;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create table cell with the below order:
        /// a:tc(TableCell)->a:txbody(TextBody)->a:p(Paragraph)->a:r(Run)->a:t(Text)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">Inserted Text in Cell</param>
        /// <returns>Return TableCell object</returns>
        private static A.TableCell CreateTextCell(string text)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                text = string.Empty;
            }

            // Declare and instantiate the table cell 
            // Create table cell with the below order:
            // a:tc(TableCell)->a:txbody(TextBody)->a:p(Paragraph)->a:r(Run)->a:t(Text)
            A.TableCell tableCell = new A.TableCell();

            //  Declare and instantiate the text body
            A.TextBody textBody = new A.TextBody();
            A.BodyProperties bodyProperties = new A.BodyProperties();
            A.ListStyle listStyle = new A.ListStyle();

            A.Paragraph paragraph = new A.Paragraph();
            A.Run run = new A.Run();
            A.RunProperties runProperties = new A.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, SmartTagClean = false };
            A.Text text2 = new A.Text();
            text2.Text = text;
            run.Append(runProperties);
            run.Append(text2);
            A.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties = new A.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US", Dirty = false };

            paragraph.Append(run);
            paragraph.Append(endParagraphRunProperties);
            textBody.Append(bodyProperties);
            textBody.Append(listStyle);
            textBody.Append(paragraph);

            A.TableCellProperties tableCellProperties = new A.TableCellProperties();
            tableCell.Append(textBody);
            tableCell.Append(tableCellProperties);

            return tableCell;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The OpenOffice PPT problem was interesting, and I was trying around with some sample code and got the following working example to create a powerpoint using .NET 6 and DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.20 (same version as you).

You need a pretty bit of hierarchy to be present for Powerpoint to open the file without complaints, even if some elements do not show up in the visual (like master slide, color palette, etc.). Taking out one section will lead to Powerpoint trying (successfully) to repair the presentation, which just programmatically adds the section again in the zipped XML.

I did not debug your code in detail, but I tried it and could reproduce your issue. Maybe the code sample in this post helps you: you might use it as template and then just add your custom layouts to the corresponding slide layout section. Have fun!

```
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

    namespace PowerpointWithOpenXmlDemo;

    using P = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
    using D = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;

    public static class OpenXMLBuilderDemo
    {
        public static void CreatePresentation(string filepath)
        {
            using var presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Create(filepath, PresentationDocumentType.Presentation);

            var presentationPart = presentationDocument.AddPresentationPart();
            presentationPart.Presentation = new P.Presentation();

            CreateSlide(presentationPart);

            presentationPart.Presentation.Save();
        }

        private static void CreateSlide(PresentationPart presentationPart)
        {
            var slideMasterIdList1 = new P.SlideMasterIdList(new P.SlideMasterId
                { Id = (UInt32Value)2147483648U, RelationshipId = "rId1" });
            var slideIdList1 = new P.SlideIdList(new P.SlideId { Id = (UInt32Value)256U, RelationshipId = "rId2" });
            var slideSize1 = new P.SlideSize { Cx = 9144000, Cy = 6858000, Type = P.SlideSizeValues.Screen4x3 };
            var notesSize1 = new P.NotesSize { Cx = 6858000, Cy = 9144000 };
            var defaultTextStyle1 = new P.DefaultTextStyle();

            presentationPart.Presentation.Append(slideMasterIdList1, slideIdList1, slideSize1, notesSize1,
                defaultTextStyle1);

            var slidePart1 = CreateSlidePart(presentationPart);
            var slideLayoutPart1 = CreateSlideLayoutPart(slidePart1);
            var slideMasterPart1 = CreateSlideMasterPart(slideLayoutPart1);
            var themePart1 = CreateTheme(slideMasterPart1);

            slideMasterPart1.AddPart(slideLayoutPart1, "rId1");
            presentationPart.AddPart(slideMasterPart1, "rId1");
            presentationPart.AddPart(themePart1, "rId5");
        }

        private static SlidePart CreateSlidePart(PresentationPart presentationPart)
        {
            var slidePart1 = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlidePart>("rId2");
            slidePart1.Slide = new P.Slide(
                new P.CommonSlideData(
                    new P.ShapeTree(
                        new P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties(
                            new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "" },
                            new P.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties(),
                            new P.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties()),
                        new P.GroupShapeProperties(new D.TransformGroup()),
                        new P.Shape(
                            new P.NonVisualShapeProperties(
                                new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)2U, Name = "Title 1" },
                                new P.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new D.ShapeLocks { NoGrouping = true }),
                                new P.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new P.PlaceholderShape())),
                            new P.ShapeProperties(),
                            new P.TextBody(
                                new D.BodyProperties(),
                                new D.ListStyle(),
                                new D.Paragraph(new D.EndParagraphRunProperties { Language = "en-US" }))))),
                new P.ColorMapOverride(new D.MasterColorMapping()));
            return slidePart1;
        }

        private static SlideLayoutPart CreateSlideLayoutPart(SlidePart slidePart1)
        {
            var slideLayoutPart1 = slidePart1.AddNewPart<SlideLayoutPart>("rId1");
            var slideLayout = new P.SlideLayout(
                new P.CommonSlideData(new P.ShapeTree(
                    new P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties(
                        new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "" },
                        new P.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties(),
                        new P.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties()),
                    new P.GroupShapeProperties(new D.TransformGroup()),
                    new P.Shape(
                        new P.NonVisualShapeProperties(
                            new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)2U, Name = "" },
                            new P.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new D.ShapeLocks { NoGrouping = true }),
                            new P.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new P.PlaceholderShape())),
                        new P.ShapeProperties(),
                        new P.TextBody(
                            new D.BodyProperties(),
                            new D.ListStyle(),
                            new D.Paragraph(new D.EndParagraphRunProperties()))))),
                new P.ColorMapOverride(new D.MasterColorMapping()));
            slideLayoutPart1.SlideLayout = slideLayout;
            return slideLayoutPart1;
        }

        private static SlideMasterPart CreateSlideMasterPart(SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart1)
        {
            var slideMasterPart1 = slideLayoutPart1.AddNewPart<SlideMasterPart>("rId1");
            var slideMaster = new P.SlideMaster(
                new P.CommonSlideData(new P.ShapeTree(
                    new P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties(
                        new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "" },
                        new P.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties(),
                        new P.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties()),
                    new P.GroupShapeProperties(new D.TransformGroup()),
                    new P.Shape(
                        new P.NonVisualShapeProperties(
                            new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)2U, Name = "Title Placeholder 1" },
                            new P.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new D.ShapeLocks { NoGrouping = true }),
                            new P.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new P.PlaceholderShape
                                { Type = P.PlaceholderValues.Title })),
                        new P.ShapeProperties(),
                        new P.TextBody(
                            new D.BodyProperties(),
                            new D.ListStyle(),
                            new D.Paragraph())))),
                new P.ColorMap
                {
                    Background1 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Light1, Text1 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Dark1,
                    Background2 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Light2, Text2 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Dark2,
                    Accent1 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent1, Accent2 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent2,
                    Accent3 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent3, Accent4 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent4,
                    Accent5 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent5, Accent6 = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Accent6,
                    Hyperlink = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.Hyperlink,
                    FollowedHyperlink = D.ColorSchemeIndexValues.FollowedHyperlink
                },
                new P.SlideLayoutIdList(new P.SlideLayoutId { Id = (UInt32Value)2147483649U, RelationshipId = "rId1" }),
                new P.TextStyles(new P.TitleStyle(), new P.BodyStyle(), new P.OtherStyle()));
            slideMasterPart1.SlideMaster = slideMaster;

            return slideMasterPart1;
        }

        private static ThemePart CreateTheme(SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart1)
        {
            var themePart1 = slideMasterPart1.AddNewPart<ThemePart>("rId5");
            var theme1 = new D.Theme { Name = "Office Theme" };

            var themeElements1 = new D.ThemeElements(
                new D.ColorScheme(
                    new D.Dark1Color(new D.SystemColor { Val = D.SystemColorValues.WindowText, LastColor = "000000" }),
                    new D.Light1Color(new D.SystemColor { Val = D.SystemColorValues.Window, LastColor = "FFFFFF" }),
                    new D.Dark2Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "1F497D" }),
                    new D.Light2Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "EEECE1" }),
                    new D.Accent1Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "4F81BD" }),
                    new D.Accent2Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "C0504D" }),
                    new D.Accent3Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "9BBB59" }),
                    new D.Accent4Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "8064A2" }),
                    new D.Accent5Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "4BACC6" }),
                    new D.Accent6Color(new D.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "F79646" }),
                    new D.Hyperlink(new D.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "0000FF" }),
                    new D.FollowedHyperlinkColor(new D.RgbColorModelHex { Val = "800080" })) { Name = "Office" },
                new D.FontScheme(
                    new D.MajorFont(
                        new D.LatinFont { Typeface = "Calibri" },
                        new D.EastAsianFont { Typeface = "" },
                        new D.ComplexScriptFont { Typeface = "" }),
                    new D.MinorFont(
                        new D.LatinFont { Typeface = "Calibri" },
                        new D.EastAsianFont { Typeface = "" },
                        new D.ComplexScriptFont { Typeface = "" })) { Name = "Office" },
                new D.FormatScheme(
                    new D.FillStyleList(
                        new D.SolidFill(new D.SchemeColor { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor }),
                        new D.GradientFill(
                            new D.GradientStopList(
                                new D.GradientStop(new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint { Val = 50000 },
                                        new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 300000 }) { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                                    { Position = 0 },
                                new D.GradientStop(new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint { Val = 37000 },
                                        new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 300000 }) { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                                    { Position = 35000 },
                                new D.GradientStop(new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint { Val = 15000 },
                                        new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 350000 }) { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                                    { Position = 100000 }
                            ),
                            new D.LinearGradientFill { Angle = 16200000, Scaled = true }),
                        new D.NoFill(),
                        new D.PatternFill(),
                        new D.GroupFill()),
                    new D.LineStyleList(
                        new D.Outline(
                            new D.SolidFill(
                                new D.SchemeColor(
                                    new D.Shade { Val = 95000 },
                                    new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 105000 }) { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor }),
                            new D.PresetDash { Val = D.PresetLineDashValues.Solid })
                        {
                            Width = 9525,
                            CapType = D.LineCapValues.Flat,
                            CompoundLineType = D.CompoundLineValues.Single,
                            Alignment = D.PenAlignmentValues.Center
                        },
                        new D.Outline(
                            new D.SolidFill(
                                new D.SchemeColor(
                                    new D.Shade { Val = 95000 },
                                    new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 105000 }) { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor }),
                            new D.PresetDash { Val = D.PresetLineDashValues.Solid })
                        {
                            Width = 9525,
                            CapType = D.LineCapValues.Flat,
                            CompoundLineType = D.CompoundLineValues.Single,
                            Alignment = D.PenAlignmentValues.Center
                        },
                        new D.Outline(
                            new D.SolidFill(
                                new D.SchemeColor(
                                    new D.Shade { Val = 95000 },
                                    new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 105000 }) { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor }),
                            new D.PresetDash { Val = D.PresetLineDashValues.Solid })
                        {
                            Width = 9525,
                            CapType = D.LineCapValues.Flat,
                            CompoundLineType = D.CompoundLineValues.Single,
                            Alignment = D.PenAlignmentValues.Center
                        }),
                    new D.EffectStyleList(
                        new D.EffectStyle(
                            new D.EffectList(
                                new D.OuterShadow(
                                        new D.RgbColorModelHex(
                                            new D.Alpha { Val = 38000 }) { Val = "000000" })
                                    {
                                        BlurRadius = 40000L, Distance = 20000L, Direction = 5400000, RotateWithShape = false
                                    })),
                        new D.EffectStyle(
                            new D.EffectList(
                                new D.OuterShadow(
                                        new D.RgbColorModelHex(
                                            new D.Alpha { Val = 38000 }) { Val = "000000" })
                                    {
                                        BlurRadius = 40000L, Distance = 20000L, Direction = 5400000, RotateWithShape = false
                                    })),
                        new D.EffectStyle(
                            new D.EffectList(
                                new D.OuterShadow(
                                        new D.RgbColorModelHex(
                                            new D.Alpha { Val = 38000 }) { Val = "000000" })
                                    {
                                        BlurRadius = 40000L, Distance = 20000L, Direction = 5400000, RotateWithShape = false
                                    }))),
                    new D.BackgroundFillStyleList(
                        new D.SolidFill(new D.SchemeColor { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor }),
                        new D.GradientFill(
                            new D.GradientStopList(
                                new D.GradientStop(
                                        new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint { Val = 50000 },
                                            new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 300000 })
                                        { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                                    { Position = 0 },
                                new D.GradientStop(
                                        new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint { Val = 50000 },
                                            new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 300000 })
                                        { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                                    { Position = 0 },
                                new D.GradientStop(
                                        new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint { Val = 50000 },
                                            new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 300000 })
                                        { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                                    { Position = 0 }),
                            new D.LinearGradientFill { Angle = 16200000, Scaled = true }),
                        new D.GradientFill(
                            new D.GradientStopList(
                                new D.GradientStop(
                                        new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint { Val = 50000 },
                                            new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 300000 })
                                        { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                                    { Position = 0 },
                                new D.GradientStop(
                                        new D.SchemeColor(new D.Tint { Val = 50000 },
                                            new D.SaturationModulation { Val = 300000 })
                                        { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.PhColor })
                                    { Position = 0 }),
                            new D.LinearGradientFill { Angle = 16200000, Scaled = true }))) { Name = "Office" });

            theme1.Append(themeElements1);
            theme1.Append(new D.ObjectDefaults());
            theme1.Append(new D.ExtraColorSchemeList());

            themePart1.Theme = theme1;
            return themePart1;
        }
    }
```